# "Back up" join option in R full_join

Tags: r, tidyverse

We're in the process of merging two very large online databases, and there's going to be a lot of manual data cleaning we're going to have to do.  For now, we're just using R to visually put the columns next to each other and eyeball the differences.

Say one of the databases looks like this:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~IRB_NO,       ~Oncore_NCT_Number, ~Oncore_Protocol_No,
  NA_character_, "NCT03150693",      "A041501",
  "0002-20",     NA_character_,      "NHPCC",
  NA_character_, "NCT05091567",      "LS-P-GO43104",
  "0003-21",     "NCT04546399",      "AALL1821",
  "0005-14",     "NCT01824836",      "CTSU-E1Z11",
  "0005-21",     NA_character_,      "LS-P-ONC-1879",
)
```

and the other looks like this:

```
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~IRB_NO,       ~Epic_NCT_Number, ~Epic_Protocol_No,
  "0001-21",     "NCT03150693",    "A041501",
  "0002-20",     NA_character_,    "NHPCC",
  NA_character_, "NCT05091567",    "LS-P-GO43104",
  NA_character_, "NCT04546399",    "AALL1821",
  "0005-14",     "NCT01824836",    "CTSU-E1Z11",
  "0005-21",     NA_character_,    "LS-P-ONC-1879",
)
```

And I want to join them on "IRB_No".  Well when I do that like so:

```
Merged<-df%>%full_join(df2, by="IRB_NO")
```

The problem is, sure that joins them on IRB_No, but if the IRB_No was blank, it still joins them, like so:

[image]

Now, SOMETIMES thats ok.  In the row I marked blue, you can tell thats probably a match because they have the same protocol_no and nct_number, but obviously a lot of the time its incorrect.

I saw the warning in R about multiple matches and handling it with "all", "any", "first", etc...  but I was thinking there's probably a better way.

Is there a way to do a "backup" column?  I.e. if irb_no is blank, then try to join by nct_number?

**Update based on comments:**

after using na_matches = "never"  I was able to help dial in my results a little more.  But for instance, these two rows (which now dont match because they have blank IRB_NO's)  are pretty obviously the same study, and it'd b great if I could "squish" the rows into one row:

[image]

Comment: What would you want your desired output to look like with these example data? Something like, `full_join(df, df2, by = c("IRB_NO", "Oncore_NCT_Number" = "Epic_NCT_Number"))`?

Comment: I'll update the question to elaborate on what a desired output could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get something like your "backup," you can compute a key in each dataframe by `dplyr::coalesce()`ing `IRB_NO` and `*_NCT_Number`. This will yield a key with the value of `IRB_NO` if not `NA` and `*_NCT_Number` if `IRB_NO` is `NA`. (And you'll want to use `na_matches = "never"` as pointed out by @dufei.)

```r
library(dplyr)

full_join(
    mutate(df, key = coalesce(IRB_NO, Oncore_NCT_Number)),
    mutate(df2, key = coalesce(IRB_NO, Epic_NCT_Number)),
    by = "key",
    na_matches = "never"
  ) %>% 
  relocate(key, Oncore_IRB_NO = IRB_NO.x, Epic_IRB_NO = IRB_NO.y)
```

```
# A tibble: 8 × 7
  key         Oncore_IRB_NO Epic_IRB_NO Oncore_NCT_Number Oncore_Protocol_No Epic_NCT_Number Epic_Protocol_No
  <chr>       <chr>         <chr>       <chr>             <chr>              <chr>           <chr>           
1 NCT03150693 NA            NA          NCT03150693       A041501            NA              NA              
2 0002-20     0002-20       0002-20     NA                NHPCC              NA              NHPCC           
3 NCT05091567 NA            NA          NCT05091567       LS-P-GO43104       NCT05091567     LS-P-GO43104    
4 0003-21     0003-21       NA          NCT04546399       AALL1821           NA              NA              
5 0005-14     0005-14       0005-14     NCT01824836       CTSU-E1Z11         NCT01824836     CTSU-E1Z11      
6 0005-21     0005-21       0005-21     NA                LS-P-ONC-1879      NA              LS-P-ONC-1879   
7 0001-21     NA            0001-21     NA                NA                 NCT03150693     A041501         
8 NCT04546399 NA            NA          NA                NA                 NCT04546399     AALL1821
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, NA will match another NA. To prevent these kinds of matches, specify `na_matches = "never"`:

```r
full_join(df, df2, join_by(IRB_NO), na_matches = "never")
#> # A tibble: 9 × 5
#>   IRB_NO  Oncore_NCT_Number Oncore_Protocol_No Epic_NCT_Number Epic_Protocol_No
#>   <chr>   <chr>             <chr>              <chr>           <chr>           
#> 1 <NA>    NCT03150693       A041501            <NA>            <NA>            
#> 2 0002-20 <NA>              NHPCC              <NA>            NHPCC           
#> 3 <NA>    NCT05091567       LS-P-GO43104       <NA>            <NA>            
#> 4 0003-21 NCT04546399       AALL1821           <NA>            <NA>            
#> 5 0005-14 NCT01824836       CTSU-E1Z11         NCT01824836     CTSU-E1Z11      
#> 6 0005-21 <NA>              LS-P-ONC-1879      <NA>            LS-P-ONC-1879   
#> 7 0001-21 <NA>              <NA>               NCT03150693     A041501         
#> 8 <NA>    <NA>              <NA>               NCT05091567     LS-P-GO43104    
#> 9 <NA>    <NA>              <NA>               NCT04546399     AALL1821
```

Comment: Ah!  Did not know about that.  I'll give this question a little bit and then possibly accept this as an answer.  I'm interested to see if anyone can show me how to use a 'backup', but at the very least this will be useful for preventing incorrect joins

Comment: Sure, take your time to pause and ponder ;) I don't think there's a way to do this sort of secondary merge key though. You might want to manually find the entries that could not be matched with `anti_join()` and merge them using your second key, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Using {powerjoin} I'm getting a different output from the accepted answer but I think this is the correct one :

```r
library(powerjoin)
power_full_join(df, df2, ~ .x$IRB_NO == .y$IRB_NO | .x$Oncore_NCT_Number == .y$Epic_NCT_Number, conflict = coalesce_xy)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   Oncore_NCT_Number Oncore_Protocol_No Epic_NCT_Number Epic_Protocol_No IRB_NO 
#>   <chr>             <chr>              <chr>           <chr>            <chr>  
#> 1 NCT03150693       A041501            NCT03150693     A041501          0001-21
#> 2 <NA>              NHPCC              <NA>            NHPCC            0002-20
#> 3 NCT05091567       LS-P-GO43104       NCT05091567     LS-P-GO43104     <NA>   
#> 4 NCT04546399       AALL1821           NCT04546399     AALL1821         0003-21
#> 5 NCT01824836       CTSU-E1Z11         NCT01824836     CTSU-E1Z11       0005-14
#> 6 <NA>              LS-P-ONC-1879      <NA>            LS-P-ONC-1879    0005-21
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You'll get the development version for this :

```
devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/powerjoin")
```

Comment: I spent 5 minutes trying to figure out what was different between your answer and the one I accepted, finally noticed that for row 7 in zephryl's answer, the NCT03150693 study was duplicated because the key was different.  So yes, I like your answer a lot.  I had already accepted theirs so I'll leave it, but thank you! Works great